# Can I change a question to another question?

Tags: support, edits, asking-questions

I have two bad questions that don't have votes or responses:

1. [get_entry_list method by SugarCRM Soap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618926/get-entry-list-method-by-sugarcrm-soap)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883369/get-one-result-to-boolean-with-nhibernate-alternative-to-take

I read the questions and I can't find any details that I might add. I think that they won't be helpful.

Can I change these questions into other questions?

Comment: You can delete your own question if you think it's not useful to others and there's no point in leaving it up. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: The first question is a bit lacking in details. "it doesn't work" is not a very descriptive problem statement. You should edit to show what you're putting into the function, if applicable, then add what you expect to get back and what you actually get back. Also add any error messages that you receive.

Comment: I edited one of your questions, tried to improve the clarity, feel free to roll it back if I changed the intent.

Comment: For the second question, what have you tried besides `.take(1)` that hasn't worked? What about the code you posted does not work how you expect? As it stands, that question is extremely poorly written, lacking in details, and could really use some fixing up. Try to revisit it and add more details about what's going on, and what you've tried as an alternative that hasn't worked.

Comment: @apaul34208 Thank you for edit my question, I see that you remove "thanks". It is a bad word to use in a question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you cannot completely re-write a question to ask a completely different question.  Ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: Ok. Whats is the better thing that i can do for dont leave this questions in the site?

Comment: @BrennQuin:-Avoid deleting your bad question, its bad for you in long term perspective. Try to improve them. But if you feel it does not help others then you have to take that action

Comment: @Piyush I'm pretty sure that's only the case if it's been downvoted.

Comment: @BrennQuin If you feel that the question is not useful and can't be improved, then feel free to delete it.  If you can figure out how to improve the question (not changing it to an entirely different question, but rather ask the same question in a way that makes it suitable for the site, and useful to others) then you should do that.  Note that if you end up asking and deleting a lot of bad questions, and aren't asking well received questions, it will inhibit your ability to continue asking questions.  If you improve your behavior going forward though, that won't be a problem for you.

Comment: @Radiodef That is not correct.

Comment: @Servy Well I assume you know better than me. (No offense intended to Piyush.) ...Seems kind of weird to penalize tumbleweeds, though.

Comment: I can not ask questions for the reason that @Servy mentioned. That is precisely the reason that I wanted to change the questions by others. But I guess I should put more effort into changing the question making it more useful or permanently erasing.