# What should I flag if a question was deleted by the OP, and undeleted with an edit that changes the question completely?

Tags: discussion

The question was deleted by the original author, and the author decided to undelete it and comes up with a completely different question by editing it.

From [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much). It was advised to roll back the question, however the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65030767/revisions) question is not a good one and has no answer and has negative vote. Since the suggested edit was full, what can I do? Wait till high-rep users to sort it out? Or raise a custom flag? Or just flag to close like a normal question?

Comment: Some more input can also be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391996/how-to-deal-with-the-op-editing-their-question-after-a-duplicate-closure-to-ask) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291949/can-i-change-a-question-to-another-question).

Comment: All links confirm roll back is the way.  But I am looking for another way in case you can't do it (which I can't do because no privilege yet and the queue is full)

Comment: Then there is only one thing for you left: leave a comment explaining that rewriting the whole question is not allowed on Stack Overflow and link one or two meta questions back your claim up. When you have 2000 reputation points, then you can rollback edits without review, but this might need some time to get there.

Comment: Leave a comment, alright. And since the original question is low quality, should I just flag it as such? Since I don't think this kind of problem shouldn't use custom flag since we can just close it and go along with our way yes?

Comment: No, flagging the current version as low quality because the old version was, doesn't work. Users deciding if the flag was warranted (i.e. doing reviews) only see the current version. So, when you want to flag, then select a flag appropriate for the current version. Also mind that "low quality" means "gibberish posts", this only applies rarely.

Comment: If the post was deleted with no Answers on it, what does it matter that the Question is rewritten?!? There are no Answers to invalidate! The meta post you linked has an Answer on it..